# How to get circular image in an imageview ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

How can i get a circular image from a UIImage and  display it on an image view.The image should be like the one displayed in IOS7 call History

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (UIImage *)getRoundedRectImageFromImage :(UIImage *)image onReferenceView :  
(UIImageView*)imageView withCornerRadius :(float)cornerRadius
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageView.bounds
                            cornerRadius:cornerRadius] addClip];
[image drawInRect:imageView.bounds];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return finalImage;
}                                                                                                     And call the method like this

imageView.image = [self getRoundedRectImageFromImage:image
                                         onReferenceView:
imageView withCornerRadius:imageView.frame.size.width/2];
imageView.clipsToBounds=YES;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```